Book about humans uplifting a planet of primitive aliens
I'm looking for a book I read in the 90's, though it was much older than that (70's or 80's, maybe?).
Humans discover a planet of primitive aliens and send a team to investigate. For some reason I can't recall (maybe they need their help to fight a war?), they need to advance their civilisation. They start by introducing the telegraph and dynamite. Soon, the aliens are inventing things for themselves. They invent space travel using tractor and pressor beams. The book ends with them having overtaken humans technologically, and massing in orbit about to invade, to put an end to primitive humanity.

I have no idea but I'd really love to read it.
